# Can I make a mock return different values if it is called several times in a recursive calls

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I have a recursive function under test `f1`. `f1` calls a database service which I am mocking.

```
def f1 {
  result = databaseservicecall(arg); //mocking this
  add result to accumulator
  exit recursion if some condition is met else call f1 again.
}
```

I want that `databaseserviecall` returns say `r1` on 1st call, `r2` in the second call and the accumulator should have `r1+r2`. Alternatively, I am also Ok if I could test that `databaseservicecall` was called 2 times and that it was passed say `arg1` and `arg2` as arguments.

Is it possible to do this in `mockito`? I thought I can use a `spy` but I don't have a real implementation of `databaseservicecall`.

Answer (score 0):

Take advantage of the `thenAnswer` feature (`doAnswer` if you are working with a spy):

```
Integer invocationCount = Integer.valueOf(0);

when(sut.databaseservicecall(any(Argument.class))).thenAnswer((invocation) ->{
   invocationCount++;

   if(invocationCount == 1) return r1;
   if(invocationCount == 2) return r2;
   if(...)


   return null;
});
```

More on the [feature](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.27.0/org/mockito/stubbing/Answer.html).

Comment: how is `invocationCount` getting changed?

Comment: manually. updated

Comment: The increment is unreachable as you leave the method before the increment.

Comment: It should be a class instance variable

Comment: Still the same result: ```invocationCount++``` can't be reached in the lambda expression. Because you leave the method called in the lambda before because invocationCount is 0. That way only r1 gets returned if you use this code without incrementing before the result is returned.

Comment: my bad, the increment should be at the beginnin

Answer (score 0):

You can just concatenate `then ()` calls.

```
when(sut.databaseservicecall(any()))
    .then(r1)
    .then(r2) ;
```